# How to remove HTML markup from a body of text within a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: regex, google-docs

I am working on cleaning up text within a google doc. The challenge is that the copy contains `HTML` markup and I am trying to remove it to be left with clean text.

I have created the following, but it seems to remove only the first instance of `HTML` code in the cell, how do I get it all out?

```
= regexreplace(C9,"\<[a-zA-Z0-9-?]*\>","")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this regular expression :

```
= regexreplace(C9,"<.*?>","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C9; "</?\S+[^<>]*>";"")
```

Or

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C9; "</?\S+[^<>]*>";)
```

Would do it.